# Change image height, using only its URL

Tags: html, css

Say we have the following HTML:

```
<img src="IMAGE-URL" />
```

And I need to change the image height in CSS, without adding classes or id.

How do I write this in CSS, something like `IMAGE-URL height: 100px` ?

Comment: Yes, it’s posible. One google search about it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

```
img[src="IMAGE-URL"] {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible if you attach style to the `img` itself in html like:

```
<img src="IMAGE-URL" style="height: 100px;"/>
```

Or in CSS to the `img` globally like:

```
img {
height 100%;
}
```

Comment: Okey, never used it and didn't know about that. The best way is the class anyway i think. Thank you for the information.